# Is plea-bargaining allowed in Judaism?

Tags: beit-din-court, edim-witnesses

Consider this form of plea-bargaining: "Plead guilty to a lesser crime.  In exchange, we won't prosecute you further and you give us information about your bosses and testify against them."

This is unfair, because a defendant who does not have this kind of information to offer gets a heavier sentence for the same crime.

Also, in Jewish law, you are not allowed to testify against yourself, possibly because:

(1) Rambam: The defendant may become depressed, even suicidal, and "confess" just to get it over with [Mishneh Torah, Sanhedrin 18:6].

(2) Yosef ibn Migash (12th-century Spanish rabbi): A confession would influence the judges, and they may not take evidence of innocence as seriously.

On the other hand, a plea-bargain is technically not "testifying" in court against yourself (except for the minor matter).

But what if the defendant is promised *immunity* in exchange for info and testimony.  Would that make the deal more Jewishly acceptable (even though unfair to others)?

**Is this or any other form of plea-bargaining allowed in Judaism?**

Comment: Are we talking in a Beit  Din here? Or civil court?

Comment: I had a bet din in mind, but wouldn't mind learning about civil court.

Comment: Who gains by the defendant admitting guilt?

Comment: I'm pretty sure plea-bargaining is entirely incompatible with the way a Beit Din works because a) as you noted you have to testify against yourself, b) witnesses are not permitted to give testimony in exchange for favors of any kind and c) a plea-bargain is in some ways a lie (you confess to comitting a lesser crime you didn't actually commit rather than the more serious crime you possibly did commit

Comment: "You confess to comitting a lesser crime you didn't actually commit "  Not necessarily.

Comment: Perhaps, there's a way around this that may be similar. I don't think that you can testify against yourself. But, of course, you can "plead guilty". Q - if one admits guilt, does this need any court / witnesses? Regardless, I think in some cases, maybe a judge can show "mercy" regarding the punishment. Perhaps that allows a leeway similar to plea bargaining where the judge says, you admit guilt for what you did, and I will reduce the punishment.

Comment: @DanF -- No mercy involved if they just want to buy your info and testimony on bigger fish.

Comment: No, in Judaism it does not work that way, unless we mimic a secular court (we might if the judges see it fit, and then anything's possible). THe reason for the mechanism you explained is the overall benefit for the society which is absent from the strict Jewish law where one should be judged for his own crimes and nothing more. THe court does not negotiate with either part - the defendant or the witnesses, it can't say - "we can hang you, but if you testify against Reuben, we'll only give you lashes".

Comment: @DanF A bais din is **forbidden** to hear testimony from the accused in which he admits to a crime (any crime). They can only hear testimony from witnesses in order to convict him (or prove him innocent). A melech is able to handle someone extra-judicialy and a bais din (when no melech exists) can process things in a similar way. However, Bais Din cannot alter the methodology of a trial.